# How to insert an external file as example in a swagger

Tags: laravel, swagger

I try to use Swagger documentation for a php project. I am using [DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger)

I would like to insert an example for the response.

I tried a lot of things like that or similar :

```
@OA\Response(

 *          response=200,
 *          description="successful operation",
 *          @OA\JsonContent(ref="./example.json")
 *       ),
```

without success.
The "example.json" contains just a json content.

[image]

The swagger displays "no example available".

My questions are :

- what is the syntax to declare an external file with annotations ?
- where to put the example file ?

Comment: To reference external example content, your API definition needs to use [`externalValue`](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#user-content-exampleexternalvalue) as [shown here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/#external). Check if L5-Swagger has an annotation for that. However, Swagger UI [doesn't render](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433) `externalValue` examples yet, so I would suggest using inline examples for now.

Comment: Ok thanks Helen for the answer. I will do inline examples, even if it not easy if the response is large.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/laravel-api-documentation-with-openapiswagger/) was referenced in a now-deleted answer.